# Azure CI/CD: On-Premise deployment failing

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to deploy my code from Azure to my local machine. The steps I followed:

1. Created deployment group
2. Run register script on my machine(the folders successfully created in C:\azagent)
3. Created pipeline.

For pipeline the generated YAML is:

```
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  
steps:
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'a31f9237-4431-41f2-b1a9-4370c7dc4828/a3a86133-79b3-437a-bc19-9665a420de4e'
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '**\*.sln'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    restoreNugetPackages: true

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)'
    Contents: '**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    CleanTargetFolder: true
    OverWrite: true
    
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

When I run the pipeline, it doesn't give any error but in release part I get an error:
[image: Error]

The solution I am using has multiple projects. I need to deploy three projects on my machine. This is the first time I am using Azure DevOps and I don't have any clue about the error. Online articles are mostly explaining about cloud deployment and I could not find much about on-premise. In short my requirement is to deploy three projects from my repo on my local machine whenever I push any changes to master branch. Is there any step by step guide to achieve the same? What is the step I missed in the setup? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the description of the error message, first you need to check whether the corresponding build pipeline is selected as the release artifact source.

[image]

Then you can check whether the  download artifacts path is consistent with the file path to the package(`Package or Folder`) of the IIS web app deploy task.

[image]

`System.DefaultWorkingDirectory` : The directory to which artifacts are downloaded during deployment of a release. The directory is cleared before every deployment if it requires artifacts to be downloaded to the agent. Same as Agent.ReleaseDirectory and System.ArtifactsDirectory.
Example: `C:\agent\_work\r1\a`

For details, please refer to [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch) document.

> my requirement is to deploy three projects from my repo on my local
> machine whenever I push any changes to master branch.Is there any step by step guide to achieve the same?

To achieve this , in yaml build pipeline ,you need to set [CI trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers): Continuous integration (CI) triggers cause a pipeline to run whenever you push an update to the specified branches.

In release pipeline , you need to set build pipeline as release [artifact source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops#artifact-sources), and then enable [Continuous deployment trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops): This instructs Azure Pipelines to create new releases automatically when it detects new artifacts are available.

Comment: Thanks. The issue was there was nothing generated in the artifacts. Your solution guided  me enough to achieve the goal. I am almost there(deploy only the project which was changed, not all the three at once) but will ask here if I need your help.